# Python pyodbc, How to return sql console information

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am currently learning how to use Pyodbc for python and have got a good understanding of how it works. However, I have one question regarding getting the current sql console results. I understand you can use cursor.fetch...() commands to return queries, but how to you return a print line? For example:

```
SQL Version:
print convert(varchar, getdate(), 14)

Pyodbc Version:
cursor.execute('print convert(varchar, getdate(), 14)')
```

In sql editor this works, but I can not seem to get pyodbc to return print results? Is there a certain cursor command I need to use or some form of logic I need to create so pyodbc can understand a print line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fetch the results and print. Replace print with select. Cursor only deals with the result set

```
 cursor.execute('select convert(varchar, getdate(), 14)')
 row = cursor.fetchone()
 if row:
     print(row)
```

Comment: When doing that it returns: pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.

Comment: ohh i did not realise that. replace print with select then?

Comment: Oh lol, you're right that does work! Would have never thought of that. Thank you!!